# Parsing Array of String into Object Properties

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an Array of airline Strings that I need to parse into properties of an array of airplane objects. Ive created the array of objects, Im having an issue using my setAirline method, the program compiles but doesn't seem to store the value, as of now I only have the setAirline just to test if it works.

```
public class Project2 {

    // Input data - Airline, Flight Number, Make, Model, Departure City, Arrival City, Departure Time, Arrival Time
    final static String [][] DATA = {
            {"Air Berlin", "4504", "Boeing", "767-300", "Zurich (ZRH)", "New York, NY (JFK)", "2-26 1000", "2-26 1325"},
            {"Qatar Airways", "212", "Boeing", "767-300", "Milano (MXP)", "New York, NY (JFK)", "2-26 1000", "2-26 1330"},
            {"Jetblue Airways", "298", "Airbus", "A320", "Tampa, FL (TPA)", "New York, NY (JFK)", "2-26 0728", "2-26 0959"},                                       
            {"Air Canada", "6851", "Airbus", "A340-300", "Dakar (DKR)", "New York, NY (JFK)", "2-26 0255", "2-26 0650"},
            {"Alaska Airlines", "1219", "Boeing", "737-800", "Boston, MA (BOS)", "New York, NY (JFK)","2-26 0940", "2-26 1055"},
            {"Delta Airlines", "6182", "Canadadair", "CRJ", "Toronto (YYZ)", "New York, NY (JFK)", "2-26 0606", "2-26 0800"},
            {"American Airline", "199", "Boeing", "767-300", "Milano (MXP)", "New York, NY (JFK)", "2-26 1010", "2-26 1330"},
            {"United Airlines", "9855", "", "", "Cairo (CAI)", "New York, NY (JFK)", "2-26 1025", "2-26 0325"},
            {"Virgin America", "483", "Airbus", "A320", "San Francisco (SFO)", "New York, NY (JFK)", "2-25 2320", "2-26 0750"},
            {"Air France", "3650", "Boeing", "767-400", "Barcelona (BCN)", "New York, NY (JFK)", "2-26 1055", "2-26 0158"},
            {"Air China", "7266", "Boeing", "757-200", "Los Angeles, CA (LAX)", "New York, NY (JFK)","2-25 2159", "2-26 0616"}
    };

    public static class Air{

    private String airline, flightNumber, make, model, departure, arrival, departureTime, arrivalTime;
    public String getAirline(Air a){return airline;};
    public void setAirline(String n){airline = n;};
    public String getFlightNum(){return flightNumber;};
    public void setFlightNum(String n){flightNumber = n;};
    public String getMake(){return make;};
    public void setMake(String n){make = n;};
    public String getModel(){return model;};
    public void setModel(String n){model = n;};
    public String getDep(){return departure;};
    public void setDep(String n){departure = n;};
    public String getArrival(){return arrival;};
    public void setArrival(String n){arrival = n;};
    public String getDepTime(){return departureTime;};
    public void setDepTime(String n){departureTime = n;};
    public String getArrivalTime(){return arrivalTime;};
    public void setArrivalTime(String n){arrivalTime = n;};

    public Air(){
            make = "";
            model = "";
    }//default

    public Air(String ma,String mo){
            this.make=ma;
            this.model=mo;
    }//2 constructor

    public Air(String air, String flight,String ma,String mo){
            this.make=ma;
            this.model=mo;
            this.airline=air;
            this.flightNumber=flight;
    }//4 constructor

    }//Air class

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create an Array of airplanes
            int size = DATA.length;
            Air[] airplanes = new Air[size];

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
                    airplanes[i].setAirline(DATA[i][j]);

    }//J-loop
    }//I-loop

    // Print out the original flight details
     // Sort it
     // Print out the updated flight details

    }//main
 }
```

Comment: Links to external sites can go dead; could you include the relevant code in your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execuse me, but I think the program is giving to you a `NullPointerException` at runtime:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {         
    // Create an Array of airplanes
    int size = DATA.length;
    Air[] airplanes = new Air[size];

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
      for (int j=0;j<8;j++) {
        airplanes[i].setAirline(DATA[i][j]);
      }//J-loop
    }//I-loop
 }//main
```

You are not initializing the `Air` objects inside the `airplane` array. How can the code `airplanes[i].setAirline(DATA[i][j]);` run without giving you an exception?!

Comment: I see, I've added airplanes[i]=new Air(); inbetween the 2 for loops but I can't seem to store each property because they have different setter methods, is there a way to use a different method for each iteration of the j loop?

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain, why your Air.getAirline() needs an Air-param? Maybe it's a typo and you would better end with this solution:

```
public class AirplanTest {

final static String[][] DATA = {
        { "Air Berlin", "4504", "Boeing", "767-300", "Zurich (ZRH)",
                "New York, NY (JFK)", "2-26 1000", "2-26 1325" },
        { "Qatar Airways", "212", "Boeing", "767-300", "Milano (MXP)",
                "New York, NY (JFK)", "2-26 1000", "2-26 1330" }
};

public static class Air {

    private String airline;

    public String getAirline() {
        return airline;
    };

    public void setAirline(String n) {
        airline = n;
    };

    public Air() {

    }// default


}// Air class

public static void main(String[] args) {        

    List<Air> airlines = new ArrayList<Air>();

    for (int i = 0; i < DATA.length; i++) {
        Air airplane = new Air();
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            airplane.setAirline(DATA[i][0]);

        }// J-loop
        airlines.add(airplane);
    }// I-loop


    // Print out the original flight details
    for(int i=0; i<airlines.size();i++){
        System.out.println(airlines.get(i).getAirline());
    }
    // Sort it
    // Print out the updated flight details


}// main
```

}

Comment: the Air-param was a typo which stopped a lot of compilation, so thanks for catching that one, I'm not familiar with the way you created the array with the "List" and tried to set it up with bracket notation, but I've been getting a runtime error:

" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8 "

heres a link to what I tried: http://pastebin.com/fpXYRFkP

Comment: In my example, airlines is an ArrayList holding Air-objects. ArrayList is much more suitable if you don't know how the list-size will change, as Java-arrays cannot be extended. And that's the problem in your implementation: First you iterate over first dimension (i), that's ok. But then you iterate over second dimension (j) and add an own increment (j+...). Imagine you reach i=10 and j=7, the setAirline() will use "Air China", because it's at [10][7], but what will the setFlightNum() use? [10][8], but j=8 actually doesn't exist in a static array. Forget about the second loop and use ArrayList.